# PowerShell v5.1 - Loading SqlServer Module does not load Read-SqlTableData or Write-SqlTableData, but Loads All Other Commands

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

On my Windows Server 2012 R2 server, the same server as my SQL Server service instance is running, I had upgraded to PowerShell v5.1. I proceeded to load the SqlServer module v21.1.18121.  All commands loaded fine except for **Read-SqlTableData** and **Write-SqlTableData**. The darndest thing! When I load the same SqlServer module on my Win10 development box, all commands are present. I suspect something like a version problem with the available .Net framework or some such, or a collision with SQL Server's modules. Anyone with thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The SqlServer module comes with the SQL Server installation and tends to be in a different version.

Module location on a SQL Server

```
(Get-Module -l SqlServer).path
 -> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\SqlServer.psd1
```

Module location from PowerShell gallery

```
(Get-Module -l SqlServer).path
-> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.0.17279\SqlServer.psd1
```

---

You can enforce PowerSell to load a module from specific location

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
Import-Module -Name (Get-Module -l SqlServer).path -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem. I've tried many things, but I think the problem stems from having the module SQLPS installed alongside SqlServer module.  (SQLPS being an older version of sqlserver).

The steps I used: (probably a little excessive)

1. Close every application that may have a reference to Powershell
   modules. For me this list included Visual Studio, SSMS, SQL Agent,
   and of course all Powershell cmd and/or IDE.
2. Open a Administrator PowerShell command shell.
3. execute: 
   `Uninstall-Module sqlps 
   Uninstall-Module sqlserver`
4. Check the Powershell modules folder to make sure you've cleared the modules.
   The place to look is:  
   `ls "c:\program files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"`
   Both of the folders "sqlps" and "sqlserver" should be missing or empty.
5. Now re-install sqlserver module: 
   `Install-Module sqlserver`
6. Check that you have the Write-SqlTableData:  
   `Get-Command -module sqlserver`

In case you suspect you have an error with versioning:  I have tried and tested sqlserver module versions: 21.1.18218 & 21.0.17099